# Ensuring minification safety in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working on an Angularjs based website, but when I try to host it online, I get the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t
```

I don't receive that error when I host the website locally, and everything works fine there.

After reading up on this, I think it has something to do with "minification safety", which I think has to do with the way I declare my angular modules.

I declare my module in main.js like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import todosList from '../imports/components/todosList/todosList';


angular.module('simple-todos', [
  angularMeteor,
  todosList.name
]);
```

And then I have another module that looks like this in todosList.js

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import template from './todosList.html';
import { Data } from '../../api/tasks.js';

class TodosListCtrl{
  //Declare a class and do stuff
}

export default angular.module('todosList', [
  angularMeteor
])
  .component('todosList', {
    templateUrl: 'imports/components/todosList/todosList.html',
    controller: TodosListCtrl

    }
  });
```

So, I pass in the controller from todosList into the main.js controller. Does why I get the error "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t" with this code? If this code is not "minification safe", how can I change it to be that way?

Comment: *Are* you using a minifier? Do you get a more descriptive error if you disable it?